# Why can't we share files in windows, so to share a file we always have to add it to a folder

Tags: windows, file, sharing

In windows to share a file we need to add it to a folder and then add user wise access to it.
Why so?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a technical limitation in [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) that prevents you from sharing a file but the DOS/Windows implementations have never supported it.

I would imagine that sharing individual files would increase the amount of [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) broadcast traffic on the network.

Mapping a share to a drive letter used to be **the** way you accessed a share and in DOS/Windows v1..3 it would be very problematic to represent files in the same way. Even in current versions of Windows a share is always treated as a container in all path parsing functions.

The SMB protocol is at least partially documented and has also been reverse engineered by the Samba team so you could investigate more if you are really interested but that does not change the fact the Windows does allow you to share a file so you are basically stuck with folders.